# Send custom type using MPI and Fortran 90

Tags: types, fortran, mpi, fortran90

In my program I have each processor calculate an array of custom type "point" which consist of 4 double precision values and 3 double complex values. I now want each processor to send its array of "point" types to the master processor.

I'm having trouble understanding how to use the MPI_type commands to send custom types. Especially with the double complex precision in the "point" type. As far as I understand MPI doesn't have a MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX type.

```
PROGRAM hello
  use mpi
  IMPLICIT NONE
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: dp = REAL(KIND(0.0D0))
  type point
    sequence
    real(kind=dp) :: x, y, z, w
    double complex :: ex, ey, ez
  end type point
  type(point), dimension(:), allocatable :: my_points
  ...

  if(rank .ne. master) then
    call MPI_SEND(my_points, count, [point?], master, 7, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierror)
  end if

  ....
END
```

Comment: Worth to note `DOUBLE COMPLEX` is a nonstandard vendor extension, not standard Fortran. I recommend `complex(dp)` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MPI standard states (§3.2.2 from the MPI 2.2 specs):

> MPI requires support of these datatypes, which match the basic datatypes of Fortran and ISO C. Additional MPI datatypes should be provided if the host language has additional data types: MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX for double precision complex in Fortran declared to be of type `DOUBLE COMPLEX`; ...

As for the construction of the datatype, it works like this. First, declare a dummy two-element array of the type or (simply use the already allocated one) in combination with the `MPI_GET_ADDRESS` to obtain the address of each field:

```
type(point) :: dummy(2)
integer(kind=MPI_ADDRESS_KIND) :: offsets(7)
integer :: ierr

call MPI_GET_ADDRESS(dummy(1)%x,  offsets(1), ierr)
call MPI_GET_ADDRESS(dummy(1)%y,  offsets(2), ierr)
call MPI_GET_ADDRESS(dummy(1)%z,  offsets(3), ierr)
call MPI_GET_ADDRESS(dummy(1)%w,  offsets(4), ierr)
call MPI_GET_ADDRESS(dummy(1)%ex, offsets(5), ierr)
call MPI_GET_ADDRESS(dummy(1)%ey, offsets(6), ierr)
call MPI_GET_ADDRESS(dummy(1)%ez, offsets(7), ierr)
```

`offsets` now contains absolute addresses so turn them into offsets relative to `dummy%x`:

```
integer :: i

do i = 2,7
  offsets(i) = offsets(i) - offsets(1)
end do
! dummy%x serves as base address, therefore set the offset to 0
offsets(1) = 0
```

The next step is to construct the MPI datatype itself:

```
integer :: oldtypes(7), lengths(7)
integer :: point_type0

! dummy%x
oldtypes(1) = MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION
lengths(1) = 1
! dummy%y
oldtypes(2) = MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION
lengths(2) = 1
! dummy%z
oldtypes(3) = MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION
lengths(3) = 1
! dummy%w
oldtypes(4) = MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION
lengths(4) = 1
! dummy%ex
oldtypes(5) = MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX
lengths(5) = 1
! dummy%ey
oldtypes(6) = MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX
lengths(6) = 1
! dummy%ez
oldtypes(7) = MPI_DOUBLE_COMPLEX
lengths(7) = 1

call MPI_TYPE_CREATE_STRUCT(7, lengths, offsets, oldtypes, point_type0, ierr)
```

(note: this code assumes that `real(kind=KIND(0.0D0))` is in fact `DOUBLE PRECISION`)

At that point you are almost ready. `point_type0` can be committed and then used to send a single element of the custom type but it might not work for arrays. The reason is the padding that the compiler might add at the end or at the beginning of the type. MPI allows explicit setting of the extent of the datatype. To do this, first determine the actual extent there should be:

```
integer(kind=MPI_ADDRESS_KIND) :: extent

! Reuse the offsets array
call MPI_GET_ADDRESS(dummy(1)%x, offsets(1), ierr)
call MPI_GET_ADDRESS(dummy(2)%x, offsets(2), ierr)

extent = offsets(2) - offsets(1)
```

(this should make it clear why you need a two-element dummy array)

Now "resize" the point datatype to the true extent and commit the resulting datatype:

```
integer :: point_type

call MPI_TYPE_CREATE_RESIZED(point_type0, 0_MPI_ADDRESS_KIND, extent, &
                             point_type, ierr)
call MPI_TYPE_COMMIT(point_type, ierr)
```

Now you are ready to use the newly registered type:

```
if(rank .ne. master) then
  call MPI_SEND(my_points(1)%x, count, point_type, &
                master, 7, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierror)
end if
```

Note that the `x` field of the first array element is given explicitly. This is done because `dummy%x` was used as the base when computing the offsets.

Some of the steps above might not be strictly necessary in your case since you have a sequence type, which might prevent the compiler from aligning the fields. Still, it is a good idea to always do it the way shown since it works both with packed and not packed types. If the `sequence` statement in the type definition is missing, the compiler is allowed to store the components in any order it deems suitable. This changes nothing since even if `dummy%x` is not the first component, those before it will simply have negative offsets.

Comment: Nice. Isn't `real(kind=KIND
(0.0D0))` guaranteed to be `DOUBLE PRECISION` by the standard?

Comment: It seems to also be able to work with  `call MPI_SEND(my_points, count, point_type, master, 7, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierror)` and `call MPI_RECV(my_points, count, point_type, from, 7, MPI_COMM_WORLD, status, ierror)`

Comment: It works since `x` is the first field and it is a sequence type. But in the general case it won't work if only the name of the array is given, i.e. if the fields are rearranged by the compiler.

Comment: @VladimirF, honestly, my knowledge of the Fortran standards is quite limited. The MPI standard states that both should be equivalent. There are provisions in the MPI standard to enable the construction of portable types, e.g. `MPI_TYPE_CREATE_F90_REAL`, but that seems badly supported in practice.

Comment: Very good answer; we should point similar questions to this one as the canonical answer for mpi_type_create_struct in fortran.